# Adding rows to table body dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add rows to an existing table that has header and footer also.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
function test() {
    var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
    var lastRow = tbl.rows.length - 1;
    var cols = tbl.rows[lastRow].cells.length;
    var row = tbl.insertRow(-1);
    for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
        row.insertCell();
    }
}
</script>
<table id="tbl" onclick="test()">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

when I click on any table I want to add new row to table body, but the issue here is the new row is added to table footer. please help me how to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You insert the row into the `tBody` element. Since there can be more than one `tBody`, you should refer to the `tBodies` prop of table at index 0.

```
var row = tbl.tBodies[0].insertRow(-1);
```

```js
function test() {
  var tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
  var lastRow = tbl.rows.length - 1;
  var cols = tbl.rows[lastRow].cells.length;
  var row = tbl.tBodies[0].insertRow(-1);
  for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
    row.insertCell().appendChild(document.createTextNode(i));
  }
}

test();
```

```html
<table id="tbl" onclick="test()">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Month</th>
      <th>Savings</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td>Sum</td>
      <td>$180</td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>January</td>
      <td>$100</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>February</td>
      <td>$80</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this. Just clone first row and then append it as child to your table. Hope it will help you

```js
 function appendRow() {
    let tbl = document.getElementById("tbl");
    let newRow = tbl.rows[0].cloneNode(true);
    tbl.appendChild(newRow);
```