# Is there a way to push down an entire function with the same "updated function"?

Tags: javascript, html, function, innerhtml

I have to make a "game" where the user has to guess a 4 digit number, and every try must be shown in a grid. I've already tried this

```
function completarDatos() {
        var datosuno = [
            document.getElementById('arriesgados').innerHTML = completar[0],
            document.getElementById('buenos').innerHTML = completar[1],
            document.getElementById('regulares').innerHTML = completar[2],
            document.getElementById('malos').innerHTML = completar[3],
            document.getElementById('intentos').innerHTML = 'Intentos: ' + intentos
        ]};
```

but it only shows the last number entered. Is there a way to show every prompt input there is in that same format, leaving the last number entered on top?

I need it to show every prompt input there is, by making the first shown the last number entered. Those five innerHTML show every element on the same line, and it has to stay that way for every entry, but each entry has to be on its separate line.

Comment: Use a table, and add a row to the table for every guess.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45110725/adding-rows-to-table-body-dynamically for how to add a row to a table.

Comment: I'm using divs for design purposes, there has to be a way to do that with divs. The function that fills in the grid is called not when the user makes the entry but when it chooses to play again

Comment: @Camila can you post a working example of your code that clearly shows the problem?

Comment: Hi @Camila , this can be acheived by simple DOM manipulation APIs , as the prev comment has said, pls get us a working sample of the code so that we can help better :)

Comment: @Camila Then add a `<div class="row">` to your grid, it's the same idea.